# Some remote addresses missing from chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, lsof

For example, if I go onto [the quantum computing stack exchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/), lsof lists stackoverflow.com, with the ip address of 198.252.206.25. Or if I go onto reddit, it lists ec2-52-87-69-120.compute-1.amazonaws.com, or a similar aws domain. However, the remote addresses for neither of these appear in the developer tools window in chrome, despite being open for the tabs they originate from.

Is this a bug, or is there a type of connection that simply won't turn up in the tools?

[image: here is the requested screenshot]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're seeing?  Some requests won't have a remote address, such as a `data:image/png;` request for an inline image (frequently used in CSS Image Sprites which Stack makes extensive use of).

Comment: What exactly would you like me to screenshot. The output of the terminal lsof showing the domain, or the developer tool output with said domain/ip addresses absent?

Comment: Also, how does a remote connection made by a site not turn up as a remote address?

Comment: Screenshot of dev tools showing the requests with no remote address.  Requests can be for a resource that is not obtained by a TCP/IP conversation.

Comment: Added in a screenshot for the qc exchange. Reddit has far too many to manage. The connection made to stackoverflow is tcp thought?

Answer (score 1):

The first request in your screenshot was blocked, maybe by an ad blocker or an extension or something, which explains why there is no remote address.

The second request is a websocket handshake.  I'm honestly not sure why websocket handshakes don't have a remote address since they happen over HTTP, other than that information is not required in the handshake and a protocol switch happens in response.

Other causes can be like my comment on the question where there is not remote hosts.  Examples are data: requests which are internal memory queries to the local machine for an already loaded resource, requests to extensions via the extension API.  I see both of those happening when loading Reddit (at least the home page) as well as a websocket handshake.

Comment: Ok so the stackoverflow connection is definitely happening due to stackexchange. If I block it, then there is no connection to it listed on lsof, if I unblock it, I can see a connection to stackoverlfow. Do you also see a lack of a remote address when the connection is made? Do you also see aws connections made while one reddit? Clicking on the posts seems to trigger the connection, but again, no remote address source.